# Debugging JavaScript in VS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

Whenever I set a breakpoint in JavaScript in Visual Studio, the debugger never breaks at the point. When I put my mouse over the breakpoint at run-time, it says "This breakpoint will currently not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

What does this mean? How do I enable JavaScript debugging/breakpoints?

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable Javascript debugging in Internet Explorer: Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced, then uncheck both "Disable Script Debugging" options.